# Is there an example of a rational number for which we do not know the integer quotient expression?

Tags: number-theory

The golden ratio is an irrational number for which we have a simple expression involving a square root, addition, and division. Then we have $\pi$ which is an irrational number which does not have a “nice” expression and is instead often represented by an infinite sum or product. What I am wondering is if there is some number $r = \frac{p}{q}$ that has been proven to be rational but we do not know what $p$ and $q$ are?

Comment: Plenty of trivial examples. For example, we know the next prime number after $2^{82,589,933}-1$ is rational (integer even!), but we don't know its numerator.

Comment: The trillionth convergent of the [regular continued fraction for $e$](http://oeis.org/A003417).  Not only do we know it to be rational, we know its value to many decimal places.

Comment: $\zeta(-200 000 000 000 001)$ should be undocumented yet, but we know it must be rational. In case of Bernoulli-numbers, Bernd Kellner, with much optimization for his small bernoulli-calc program has, if I recall correctly, once computed and documented explicitely $B_n$ with $n=1 e6$ or $1e7$. So one of his records (they are even online documented), with index $n+2$, might be another example.